# Redshift cast to text type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Im trying to alter a view written in redshift a few years ago, the view has a column of type text and other views are depending on it so I can't drop it, once I'm trying to "create or replace the view" I get this error

> "Invalid operation: cannot change data type of view column
> "employee_status";

the column originally was of type ::TEXT

```
case when 1=1 then 'someText'::TEXT else 'otherText'::TEXT end as employee_status
```

but once I'm trying to update this view the column is created as varchar(10) which creates this conflict.
is there a way to force the column type to be created as TEXT.
was reading the docs and not sure if this was changed with recent updates

**EDIT:**
Here a sample of the view definition:

```
create or replace view sc.test 
as select column1...,
case when 1=1 then 'someText'::TEXT else 'otherText'::TEXT end as employee_status
where... some condition
```

I want to change some condition but then getting the issue of the datatype for the column employee_status as it's created as varchar and not text, so I cant update the view.

EDIT2:
here is the column type for the view, with type Text:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the definition of the original view?  This will help with the definition of the column and type of view in question.  Also, I expect you may have an issue with your quote type - double quotes are meant to indicate table or column names. This may be right but would be good to clarify.

Comment: you are correct I haven't posted the original query as tried to create a simple example, yes the text is in a single quotes

Comment: So how confident are you that the original view has this column defined as TEXT?  Remember that TEXT is an alias for VARCHAR(256) in Redshift.  Is this a normal view or a materialized view or a late binding view?

Comment: it's a normal view, I have the definition of the original view, I think it was created 3 years ago or so, even running the original definition raises this error, I'm suspecting something were changed with Redshift regarding the text data type, I have tried to recreate the column as varchar(256), varchar(max),, but did not work

Comment: Are you looking at the Redshift system tables for the existing view definition?  See https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_view_ddl.sql - just take the SELECT out of this view definition and add a where clause for the view name.

Comment: my question is that why redshift creates the column as varchar where I'm specifying the type to be casted as text ? this would create conflicts with old views where the columns where saved as actual text type and not varchar, now editing these views is not possible meaning so they have to be dropped and recreated .I cant' drop my current view since there are more than 20 views that depend on.. and at the same time I can't replace it due to this datatype error

Comment: Data type TEXT doesn't exist in Redshift.  The word TEXT is an alias for the word VARCHAR.  see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html

Comment: exactly, that what confused me, the old views meta showed that a text type column existed. please see the attached image

Comment: Redshift supports all these aliases so that people coming from different SQL languages can feel comfortable but I think we are off track.  Since the "original" definition cannot be reapplies to the view it is not clear to me that the issue is with the column you are trying to change or another one.  The error you are getting is for this exact column when you try to reapply the original view definition?

Comment: VARCHAR length is a possibility of what is tripping you up

Comment: yes the error I'm getting is when I'm updating this view by running the script again, not able to modify it or drop it..

Comment: So did you generate the source SQL for the view using the AWSLABS script I pointed to?  Did this create the same error?

Comment: yes, sir the same DDL creates the same error here is the part of the ddl where the column would be created as TEXT:
`
CASE 
WHEN 1=1 THEN 'Terminated'::text ELSE 'Active'::text end as employee_status
`

Comment: OK, seems like something more basic is going on.  Can you create a new view with the same SQL?  It could be a source table mismatch possibly caused by a search_path different than when the view was created.

Comment: yes, I could create a new view with the same script, but when I do so the column is created as varchar(10)

Comment: OK, interesting.  Redshift must be getting this size from the DDL of the referenced tables.  This could be a recent optimization (past 3 years).  Theory: Redshift wants to make this column size 10 b/c this is a large as the data can be but the original is longer.  This change is size is raising the error.  Try defining the view with the original size of this column.

Comment: exactly. tried multiple things with column size, could not know what its the original size I must use, I tried varchar, varchar(max), varchar(256).. text and still getting the same issue.

Comment: Look in information_schema.columns for your view and column name.  There should be a character_maximum_length field that will tell you the current length.  (I don't have my cluster up at the moment so working from existing code I have)

Comment: Yes, already tried this:

SELECT ordinal_position AS POSITION
,column_name
,data_type
,CASE
WHEN character_maximum_length IS NOT NULL THEN character_maximum_length
ELSE numeric_precision
END AS max_length
,is_nullable
,column_default AS default_value
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'myview'
AND table_schema = 'ts'
ORDER BY ordinal_position

The Column type is text and the length is null and numeric_precision is null as well

Comment: I'm running out of ideas but it looks like the size change is the cause.  Others may have debugged this before and can help.  If you have Redshift support you may want to submit a ticket.  The path is to rename and replace this view and all dependent views.  You can make a script to do this in a single transaction.  Then once the new versions are committed you can drop the old versions.

Comment: yes I think so, have been trying to avoid this solution it's a nested dependency between the views

Comment: There's too much to read here in the comments, but I might have one or two useful things to say.  The 'text' type is I think a real type (it's in `pg_type`, it's not just an alias) but it is the same as `varchar(256)`.  However, with views, when you have a varchar column, the length of the type for that column will vary, being the longest possible output for that column from the SQL which forms the view.  So if you cast to `text`, you'll get `varchar(something)`, depending on what your SQL is doing.

Comment: This is also BTW how Redshift knows to complain at you if you produce a column which can emit incompatible types, say `int` or `char`.  The `char` and `varchar` types are considered compatible regardless of length.